# Before create doesn't work on my sequelize model

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

Before create doesn't work on my sequelize model
I created a template, but for some reason my before create doesn't work and I don't know what it can be anymore.

```
async createUser(req,res){
    const { name,email,login,password } = req.body
        const verify = await Users.findOne({where:{login: login}});

        if(verify){ return res.status(400).json({result: 'User already exists'})}

        const user = await Users.create({name,email,login,password});
}
```

model:

```
class Users extends Model {
    static init(sequelize){
        super.init({
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            email: DataTypes.STRING,
            login: DataTypes.STRING,
            password: DataTypes.STRING,
        }, {sequelize, tableName:'users'},
         {
            hooks: {
              beforeCreate: (user) => {
                console.log('ae');
              },

            },
        }
        )
```

do not enter my before and do not return my console.log

Comment: Same problem here with `beforeDelete`/`afterDelete`. Have you found out what the solution might be?

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `hooks` option inside the second object parameter. `Model.init()` interface is:

```js
public static init<M extends Model = Model>(this: ModelCtor<M>, attributes: ModelAttributes, options: InitOptions<M>): void;
```

Here is a working example:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';

class User extends Model {}
User.init(
  {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    login: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'users',
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: (user) => {
        console.log('======== ae ========');
      },
    },
  },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    await User.create({ name: 'Alanna', email: 'example@gmail.com', login: 'value', password: '123' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

The execution results:

```sh
======== ae ========
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "users" ("id","name","email","login","password") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING *;
```

Now, the `beforeCreate` hook of the `User` model works fine.

Comment: Works for me :)